# ANCOVA versus Hierarchical Regression in SPSS (images included)

Tags: regression, spss, ancova

I'm conducting an analysis in SPSS looking at the relationship between a categorical independent variable (with three levels) against a continuous dependent variable, but wanting to control for the effects of gender on the dependent variable (categorical covariate).

I initially conducted an ANOVA (general linear model> univariate) as well as a regression (regression> linear; using dummy variables for the my categorical independent variable) and obtained an identical significance/ F statistic for both tests.

As far as I understand an ANCOVA and hierarchical regression ought to just extend upon that initial outcome but also account for the covariate and should therefore produce the same significance/ F statistic for both tests. Despite this, when I run each of these including the gender covariate (by adding it in the covariate box in the general linear model> univariate or by adding it as a dummy in the first block in regression> linear before adding the other dummy variables in the second block) I get a different significance/ F statistic between the two tests.

Should there theoretically be a difference between these tests once the covariate is added in, and if so is there somewhere I am going wrong in entering the covariate? In addition, which test would be the most appropriate to report on given these variables?

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is hard to follow.  Can you paste in your output? What is different / the same?

Comment: Initial ANOVA vs regression (without the covariate)
http://imgur.com/TpMuxB1

ANCOVA vs regression (with the covariate added)
http://imgur.com/a/9AWfq

Comment: What I am asking is whether the two tests with a covariate should give a different result or not (given that I understand them to be testing the same thing in theory)

Comment: Is there something different in the formulae behind these two tests when accounting for a covariate? Or should they be the same as is the case in the ANOVA and regression without the covariate?